# Using npm from the command line with Visual Studio 2015 Web Project

Tags: visual-studio, npm, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

After installing Visual Studio 2015 I am able to use the new editor features to add dependencies to Node packages and restore etc from within a Web project as per this documentation:  http://webtooling.visualstudio.com/package-managers/npm/

Presumably Visual Studio must install node/npm somewhere in order to support these features, however it does not seem to modify my PATH to make these tools available on the command line (or via Visual Studio 2015 Command Prompt).

If I want to perform some npm operations on my project from the command line can I do this without installing node/npm again (which might become out of sync with the version of npm/node that Visual Studio is using) or is there a way to access the node/npm installation Visual Studio is using from the command line?

Answer (score 2):

VS2015 installs node using Joyent's installer. It depends on the system-wide install and it does not have it's own specific or local version.

If you're command line is unable to find node.exe, I would first check your path property in your environment variables and add it if it's missing (it should be C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs). If you see node's install directory there but still can't access it from the command line, reboot. Sometimes Windows needs to restart before it uses the updated path variable.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I do not seem to have a node.js installation under Program Files. I believe VS installs node via Joyent only when node.js tools are selected as an option in the Visual Studio Installation configuration. I did not select this option when installing VS. But, I think VS must still be installing node and npm somewhere if only to make the ASP.NET 5 tooling work...

Comment: Interesting... we've heard reports of cases where node installs to a different location but we haven't figured out what causes it. This is a good clue. In any case, node must be somewhere in your machine. Can you search for it and tell me where you found it?

Comment: I found node, bower and gulp-cli in this directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\External

Comment: Thanks. This is news to me and my team, we didn't know there could be different copies of node installed by vs. I am following up with the ASP.Net team to see if there are side effects.

In the meantime, installing the Tools for Apache Cordova will also install Node, and that I'm sure will put it in program files. I would suggest using that node from the command line instead of this special one in the vs install directory.

Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help Michael. Much appreciated. If I'm not planning on using Cordova then presumably installing node independently of VS is an equally good option?